# How decode QRcode selected in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, qr-code, zxing

I would like to decode a QRcode selected in a worksheet excel but in vba. So I have this piece of code from Zxing library.

```
Function Decode_QR_Code_From_Byte_Array() 
    Dim reader As IBarcodeReader 
    Dim rawRGB(1000) As Byte 
    Dim res As Result 

    Set reader = New BarcodeReader 

    reader.options.PossibleFormats.Add BarcodeFormat_QR_CODE 

    Rem TODO: load bitmap data to byte array rawRGB 
    Set res = reader.DecodeImageBytes(rawRGB, 10, 10, BitmapFormat.BitmapFormat_Gray8) 

End Function
```

My main problems are:

- How worked with a selected qrcode in the worksheet in VBA ? (macro) Because I don't want to use "from file"
- How decode it with the code ?

Comment: does this  https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/wiki/Using-ZXing.Net-with-VBA-(COM-Interop) answers?

Comment: @p._phidot_ but how to use it ? I don't understand

Comment: Did you download `zxing.interop.dll` and registered it? If yes, where from did you download it? From [here](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net)?

Comment: insert the byte array value in the rawRGB variable (imho) . | If you are reading it from a QR code picture, I'm not sure how to reference it (an OLE object?) in excel VBA (plus I think need to use 'Decode_QR_Code_From_File()' instead of the one you post ).

Comment: yes I did download and install everything and it is functional. Then I integrate more than 800 QRcodes in my excel file. the goal is therefore to take a sample of some qrcodes, decoded them and check their values in order to know if they are listed in the right place

Comment: Did you encode the QR codes in discussion using the same `zxing.interop.tlb`?

Comment: Even if not encoded using the same `tlb`, what type of shape are the QR Code to be read? Are they shapes having a QR code like picture (.Fill.UserPicture)? If yes, I would have a solution to read them. If you do  not know their type try selecting such a QR code shape and try the next code lines, please: `Dim sh As Shape` `Set sh = Selection.ShapeRange(1)` `sh.CopyPicture: Range("A1").Select: ActiveSheet.Paste`. Does it copy the picture of the QR code in cell "A" as Picture?

Comment: Please, select such a QR code shape and run this code line: `Debug.Print Selection.ShapeRange(1).Type`, What does it return in `Immediate Window`? 1, 11, 13?

Answer (score 1):

You did not answer my clarification questions... I tried making a piece of code dealing with three shape types. Please, try the next code. It assumes that the QR code shapes have similar names, able to be used to recognize them. I tried the first two characters to be "QR", but it can be changed for your case. If not a pattern, I also suppose that they should be added on a specific column. This can also be used to identify them.

Please, try the next approach:

```
Sub DecodeQR()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Shape, chQR As ChartObject, QRFile As String
   
   QRFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\QRPict.png"
   Set ws = ActiveSheet                 'any sheet to be processed
   'Add a chart helper to export QR picture:
   Set chQR = ws.ChartObjects.Add(left:=1, top:=1, width:=100, height:=100)
       
   For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes    ' iterate between existing shapes
        If left(sh.Name, 2) = "QR" Or left(sh.Name, 2) = "Pi" Then 'process only QR shapes
            chQR.width = sh.width: chQR.height = sh.height         'chart dimensions
            If sh.Type = 1 Or sh.Type = 11 Or sh.Type = 13 Then    'shapes keeping a picture
                ExportQRPict sh, QRFile, chQR 'export picture to be used for decoding
                Debug.Print sh.TopLeftCell.Address, Decode_QR_Code_From_File(QRFile) 'decoding
            Else
                Debug.Print "Unappropriate shape at " & sh.TopLeftCell.Address
            End If
        End If
   Next sh
   Kill QRFile: chQR.Delete
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub ExportQRPict(QRSh As Shape, QRFile As String, ch As ChartObject, Optional boolPict As Boolean)
   QRSh.CopyPicture: ch.Activate: ActiveChart.Paste
   ch.Chart.Export fileName:=QRFile, FilterName:="PNG"
End Sub
```

```
Function Decode_QR_Code_From_File(pictPath) As String
   Dim reader As IBarcodeReader
   Dim res As result

   Set reader = New BarcodeReader

   reader.Options.PossibleFormats.Add BarcodeFormat_QR_CODE

   Set res = reader.DecodeImageFile(pictPath)
   Decode_QR_Code_From_File = res.text
End Function
```

Usually, the QR code shapes are placed to the right side of the cell keeping the text to be encoded. If this is the case, or any relation between the shape cell to belong and the cell keeping the text to be encoded exists, the above code can be adapted to check if the decoded text is the same with the reference one.

Comment: @Thony Nadhir: Didn't you find some time to test the above code?